# how to monitor wifi networks and remove them in windows mobile..?

Tags: wifi, windows-mobile, device-driver, mobile-development

I have certain windows mobile devices which supposed to be only connected to a known wifi network. so the user of the device can not connect to other wifi network as they intend. how can i tackle this problem. your kind guidance is required. i know this is constrained by many hard factors. but i would like to know if there is a way. Thank you

first i thought watching and deleting wifi network profiles. but am afraid performing such things will allow on windows mobile. then i to find a way to close other application connection if its connected to unwanted network. then i tried to find a way to write a driver to mobile device driver (though it is a tough task) ,at least to understand the possibility

Comment: Normally, such feature is handled by 3rd party supplicants like Funk Odyssey or Summit. You may first disable popups about new networks. Configure only one network to connect to and hope the user does not open the Connection settings and change this. See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg155011.aspx

Comment: see also https://opennetcf.com/2011/08/19/a-service-for-scanning-and-connecting-to-wifi-networks-from-the-cf/ and here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms894771.aspx